# Test steps vs Sub tests and creating an extension for Azure DevOps test runner

Tags: azure, testing, devops

I have been looking at the Azure DevOps API in order to create an extension with the following capabilities:

1. add a new status to each test step (not just passed/failed) and
2. make it easier to attach images or other files with fewer clicks.

I have been looking over the Azure DevOps API in the hopes of finding something relevant.

The only thing I've come across that is possibly related is commands for Subtests, however I am not entirely sure subtests are the one and the same thing as test steps. If so, then it should not be too hard to develop this? Below I've copy-pasted the related functions.

My exact question is: What is the difference between subtests and test steps if any, and secondly, how would I go on about developing these features for test steps?

```
 createTestResultAttachment(attachmentRequestModel: TestInterfaces.TestAttachmentRequestModel, project: string, runId: number, testCaseResultId: number): Promise<TestInterfaces.TestAttachmentReference>;
createTestSubResultAttachment(attachmentRequestModel: TestInterfaces.TestAttachmentRequestModel, project: string, runId: number, testCaseResultId: number, testSubResultId: number): Promise<TestInterfaces.TestAttachmentReference>;
```